# void operator delete [](void*) error, when compiling with gcc only in Release

Tags: c++, delete-operator

gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0
Compiler warnings flags = -Wall;-Werror
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED = ON

I am using a library (old version of TNT) that implements some linear algebra functionality with the following:

```
/*
*
* Template Numerical Toolkit (TNT): Linear Algebra Module
*
* Mathematical and Computational Sciences Division
* National Institute of Technology,
* Gaithersburg, MD USA
*
*
* This software was developed at the National Institute of Standards and
* Technology (NIST) by employees of the Federal Government in the course
* of their official duties. Pursuant to title 17 Section 105 of the
* United States Code, this software is not subject to copyright protection
* and is in the public domain.  The Template Numerical Toolkit (TNT) is
* an experimental system.  NIST assumes no responsibility whatsoever for
* its use by other parties, and makes no guarantees, expressed or implied,
* about its quality, reliability, or any other characteristic.
*
* BETA VERSION INCOMPLETE AND SUBJECT TO CHANGE
* see http://math.nist.gov/tnt for latest updates.
*
*/



// C compatible matrix: row-oriented, 0-based [i][j] and 1-based (i,j) indexing
//

#ifndef CMAT_H
#define CMAT_H

#include "subscript.h"
#include "vec.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#ifdef TNT_USE_REGIONS
#include "region2d.h"
#endif

namespace TNT
{

    template <class T>
    class Matrix 
    {
    
      public:
    
        typedef Subscript   size_type;
        typedef         T   value_type;
        typedef         T   element_type;
        typedef         T*  pointer;
        typedef         T*  iterator;
        typedef         T&  reference;
        typedef const   T*  const_iterator;
        typedef const   T&  const_reference;
    
        Subscript lbound() const { return 1;}
     
      protected:
        Subscript m_;
        Subscript n_;
        Subscript mn_;      // total size
        T* v_;                  
        T** row_;           
        T* vm1_ ;       // these point to the same data, but are 1-based 
        T** rowm1_;

        // internal helper function to create the array
        // of row pointers
    
        void initialize(Subscript M, Subscript N)
        {
            mn_ = M*N;
            m_ = M;
            n_ = N;
    
            v_ = new T[mn_]; 
            row_ = new T*[M];
            rowm1_ = new T*[M];
    
            assert(v_  != NULL);
            assert(row_  != NULL);
            assert(rowm1_ != NULL);
    
            T* p = v_;              
            vm1_ = v_ - 1;
            for (Subscript i=0; i<M; i++)
            {
                row_[i] = p;
                rowm1_[i] = p-1;
                p += N ;
                
            }
    
            rowm1_ -- ;     // compensate for 1-based offset
        }
       
        void copy(const T*  v)
        {
            Subscript N = m_ * n_;
            Subscript i;
    
    #ifdef TNT_UNROLL_LOOPS
            Subscript Nmod4 = N & 3;
            Subscript N4 = N - Nmod4;
    
            for (i=0; i<N4; i+=4)
            {
                v_[i] = v[i];
                v_[i+1] = v[i+1];
                v_[i+2] = v[i+2];
                v_[i+3] = v[i+3];
            }
    
            for (i=N4; i< N; i++)
                v_[i] = v[i];
    #else
    
            for (i=0; i< N; i++)
                v_[i] = v[i];
    #endif      
        }
    
        void set(const T& val)
        {
            Subscript N = m_ * n_;
            Subscript i;
    
    #ifdef TNT_UNROLL_LOOPS
            Subscript Nmod4 = N & 3;
            Subscript N4 = N - Nmod4;
    
            for (i=0; i<N4; i+=4)
            {
                v_[i] = val;
                v_[i+1] = val;
                v_[i+2] = val;
                v_[i+3] = val; 
            }
    
            for (i=N4; i< N; i++)
                v_[i] = val;
    #else
    
            for (i=0; i< N; i++)
                v_[i] = val;
            
    #endif      
        }
        
        void destroy()
        {
            /* do nothing, if no memory has been previously allocated */
            if(v_ == NULL) return ;
    
            /* if we are here, then matrix was previously allocated */
            if(v_ != NULL) delete [] (v_);     
            if(row_ != NULL) delete [] (row_);
    
            /* return rowm1_ back to original value */
            rowm1_ ++;
            if(rowm1_ != NULL ) delete [] (rowm1_);
        }
    
    
      public:
    
        operator T**(){ return  row_; }
        operator T**() const { return row_; }
    
    
        Subscript size() const { return mn_; }
    
        // constructors
    
        Matrix() : m_(0), n_(0), mn_(0), v_(0), row_(0), vm1_(0), rowm1_(0) {};
    
        Matrix(const Matrix<T> &A)
        {
            initialize(A.m_, A.n_);
            copy(A.v_);
        }
    
        Matrix(Subscript M, Subscript N, const T& value = T())
        {
            initialize(M,N);
            set(value);
        }
    
        Matrix(Subscript M, Subscript N, const T* v)
        {
            initialize(M,N);
            copy(v);
        }

        // destructor
        //
        ~Matrix()
        {
            destroy();
        }
    
    
        // reallocating
        //
        Matrix<T>& newsize(Subscript M, Subscript N)
        {
            if(num_rows() == M && num_cols() == N)
                return *this;
    
            destroy();
            initialize(M,N);
            
            return *this;
        }
    
    
        // assignments
        //
        Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T> &A)
        {
            if(v_ == A.v_)
                return *this;
    
            if(m_ == A.m_  && n_ == A.n_)      // no need to re-alloc
                copy(A.v_);
    
            else
            {
                destroy();
                initialize(A.m_, A.n_);
                copy(A.v_);
            }
    
            return *this;
        }
            
        Matrix<T>& operator=(const T& scalar)
        { 
            set(scalar); 
            return *this;
        }
    
    
        Subscript dim(Subscript d) const 
        {
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
           assert( d >= 1);
            assert( d <= 2);
    #endif
            return (d==1) ? m_ : ((d==2) ? n_ : 0); 
        }
    
        Subscript num_rows() const { return m_; }
        Subscript num_cols() const { return n_; }
    
    
    
    
        inline T* operator[](Subscript i)
        {
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
            assert(0<=i);
            assert(i < m_) ;
    #endif
            return row_[i];
        }
    
        inline const T* operator[](Subscript i) const
        {
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
            assert(0<=i);
            assert(i < m_) ;
    #endif
            return row_[i];
        }
    
        inline reference operator()(Subscript i)
        { 
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
            assert(1<=i);
            assert(i <= mn_) ;
    #endif
            return vm1_[i]; 
        }
    
        inline const_reference operator()(Subscript i) const
        { 
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
            assert(1<=i);
            assert(i <= mn_) ;
    #endif
            return vm1_[i]; 
        }
    
    
    
        inline reference operator()(Subscript i, Subscript j)
        { 
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
            assert(1<=i);
            assert(i <= m_) ;
            assert(1<=j);
            assert(j <= n_);
    #endif
            return  rowm1_[i][j]; 
        }
    
    
        
        inline const_reference operator() (Subscript i, Subscript j) const
        {
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
            assert(1<=i);
            assert(i <= m_) ;
            assert(1<=j);
            assert(j <= n_);
    #endif
            return rowm1_[i][j]; 
        }
    
    
    
    #ifdef TNT_USE_REGIONS
    
        typedef Region2D<Matrix<T> > Region;
        
    
        Region operator()(const Index1D &I, const Index1D &J)
        {
            return Region(*this, I,J);
        }
    
    
        typedef const_Region2D< Matrix<T> > const_Region;
        const_Region operator()(const Index1D &I, const Index1D &J) const
        {
            return const_Region(*this, I,J);
        }
    
    #endif
  
    };   //End public declarations
    
    
    /* ***************************  I/O  ********************************/
    
    template <class T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, const Matrix<T> &A)
    {
        Subscript M=A.num_rows();
        Subscript N=A.num_cols();
    
        s << M << " " << N << "\n";
    
        for (Subscript i=0; i<M; i++)
        {
            for (Subscript j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                s << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
            s << "\n";
        }
    
    
        return s;
    }
    
    template <class T>
    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &s, Matrix<T> &A)
    {
    
        Subscript M, N;
    
        s >> M >> N;
    
        if( !(M == A.num_rows() && N == A.num_cols() ))
        {
            A.newsize(M,N);
        }
    
    
        for (Subscript i=0; i<M; i++)
            for (Subscript j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                s >>  A[i][j];
            }
    
    
        return s;
    }
    
    // *******************[ basic matrix algorithms ]***************************
    
    
    template <class T>
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &A, 
        const Matrix<T> &B)
    {
        Subscript M = A.num_rows();
        Subscript N = A.num_cols();
    
        assert(M==B.num_rows());
        assert(N==B.num_cols());
    
        Matrix<T> tmp(M,N);
        Subscript i,j;
    
        for (i=0; i<M; i++)
            for (j=0; j<N; j++)
                tmp[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
    
        return tmp;
    }
    
    template <class T>
    Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T> &A, 
        const Matrix<T> &B)
    {
        Subscript M = A.num_rows();
        Subscript N = A.num_cols();
    
        assert(M==B.num_rows());
        assert(N==B.num_cols());
    
        Matrix<T> tmp(M,N);
        Subscript i,j;
    
        for (i=0; i<M; i++)
            for (j=0; j<N; j++)
                tmp[i][j] = A[i][j] - B[i][j];
    
        return tmp;
    }
    
    template <class T>
    Matrix<T> mult_element(const Matrix<T> &A, 
        const Matrix<T> &B)
    {
        Subscript M = A.num_rows();
        Subscript N = A.num_cols();
    
        assert(M==B.num_rows());
        assert(N==B.num_cols());
    
        Matrix<T> tmp(M,N);
        Subscript i,j;
    
        for (i=0; i<M; i++)
            for (j=0; j<N; j++)
                tmp[i][j] = A[i][j] * B[i][j];
    
        return tmp;
    }
    
    
    template <class T>
    Matrix<T> transpose(const Matrix<T> &A)
    {
        Subscript M = A.num_rows();
        Subscript N = A.num_cols();
    
        Matrix<T> S(N,M);
        Subscript i, j;
    
        for (i=0; i<M; i++)
            for (j=0; j<N; j++)
                S[j][i] = A[i][j];
    
        return S;
    }
    
    
        
    template <class T>
    inline Matrix<T> matmult(const Matrix<T>  &A, 
        const Matrix<T> &B)
    {
    
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
        assert(A.num_cols() == B.num_rows());
    #endif
    
        Subscript M = A.num_rows();
        Subscript N = A.num_cols();
        Subscript K = B.num_cols();
    
        Matrix<T> tmp(M,K);
        T sum;
    
        for (Subscript i=0; i<M; i++)
        for (Subscript k=0; k<K; k++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (Subscript j=0; j<N; j++)
                sum = sum +  A[i][j] * B[j][k];
    
            tmp[i][k] = sum; 
        }
    
        return tmp;
    }
    
    template <class T>
    inline Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>  &A, 
        const Matrix<T> &B)
    {
        return matmult(A,B);
    }
    
    template <class T>
    inline int matmult(Matrix<T>& C, const Matrix<T>  &A, 
        const Matrix<T> &B)
    {
    
        assert(A.num_cols() == B.num_rows());
    
        Subscript M = A.num_rows();
        Subscript N = A.num_cols();
        Subscript K = B.num_cols();
    
        C.newsize(M,K);
    
        T sum;
    
        const T* row_i;
        const T* col_k;
    
        for (Subscript i=0; i<M; i++)
        for (Subscript k=0; k<K; k++)
        {
            row_i  = &(A[i][0]);
            col_k  = &(B[0][k]);
            sum = 0;
            for (Subscript j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                sum  += *row_i * *col_k;
                row_i++;
                col_k += K;
            }
            C[i][k] = sum; 
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    template <class T>
    Vector<T> matmult(const Matrix<T>  &A, const Vector<T> &x)
    {
    
    #ifdef TNT_BOUNDS_CHECK
        assert(A.num_cols() == x.dim());
    #endif
    
        Subscript M = A.num_rows();
        Subscript N = A.num_cols();
    
        Vector<T> tmp(M);
        T sum;
    
        for (Subscript i=0; i<M; i++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            const T* rowi = A[i];
            for (Subscript j=0; j<N; j++)
                sum = sum +  rowi[j] * x[j];
    
            tmp[i] = sum; 
        }
    
        return tmp;
    }
    
    template <class T>
    inline Vector<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>  &A, const Vector<T> &x)
    {
        return matmult(A,x);
    }

} // namespace TNT

#endif
// CMAT_H
```

and the destructor is implemented in terms of a function as follows:

```
        void destroy()
        {
            /* do nothing, if no memory has been previously allocated */
            if(v_ == NULL) return ;
    
            /* if we are here, then matrix was previously allocated */
            if(v_ != NULL) delete [] (v_);     
            if(row_ != NULL) delete [] (row_);
    
            /* return rowm1_ back to original value */
            rowm1_ ++;
            if(rowm1_ != NULL )
                  delete[] rowm1_;
        }
```

When compiling for Debug, there are no errors or warnings. However, I get an error when compiling for Release.

Specifically, this results in the compile-time error:

```
error: ‘void operator delete [](void*)’ called on pointer ‘*(TNT::Matrix<double>*)((char*)this + 48).TNT::Matrix<double>::rowm1_’ with nonzero offset 8 [-Werror=free-nonheap-object]
  192 |             delete[] rowm1_;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The C++ standard version number doesn't seem to matter (ie, 11/14/17).

Also, I don't receive any warnings or errors in either Debug or Release mode from MSVC 2019.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.
In addition, I only get it for the `rowm1_` variable and not for `row_` variable, which seems to be being initialized and deleted in the same way.

I've tried to change the delete function, but everything I do doesn't work or results in a compile time error.

Comment: "return rowm1_ back to original value" and `rowm1_ ++`... Why? Where and when are you modifying `rowm1_` to point somewhere else than what was returned by `new T*[M]`?

Comment: By the way, in the `destroy` function after the check `if(v_ == NULL)` you don't need the extra check `if(v_ != NULL)`.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. That `rowm1_++` looks fishy and makes no sense when the posted code is considered, maybe it has something to do with code you did not show?

Comment: [OT] `delete[]` null pointer is fine, no need to protect against `nullptr`.

Comment: As I understand it, the "m1" is meant for "minus 1", in order to facilitate the difference between base-0 and base-1 style indexing. This was for accommodate Fortran and C style indexing.

Comment: "compensate for 1-based offset" -- do yourself a huge, huge favor: learn and adapt to C++'s natural 0-based array offsets. These kinds of hacks for working arounds meatbags' prejudices will always, always end in tears. Not to mention undefined behavior, as in this case.

Comment: By the way, `rowm1_ -- ;` is undefined since it attempts to decrement the pointer outside the array.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm fine with C style. This comes directly from a library in a code that I am tasked with maintaining. Due to time constraints, we'd like to continue to use this library as-is, or mostly so.

Comment: In `delete [] rowm1_`, `rowm1_` must be either the null pointer or a pointer returned from `new[]`. We know it isn't the null pointer (both because of the test and because incrementing a null pointer is undefined). However, since it can't be a pointer returned from `new[]` if the increment is to be valid, it must be an invalid pointer. Compilers are very clever.

Comment: who wrote the code? I think I understand the thing about 1-based indices, but that `rowm1_ ++;` seems to be totally misguided. `rowm1_ = new T*[M];` must be deleted via `delete  [] rowm1_;`. That its elements have an offset of 1 is irrelevant for deleting the array itself

Comment: It's kind of depressing that this code is from the Mathematical and Computational Sciences Division at NIST. They really should know better.

Comment: If one-based indexing is required, then it should be handled in the `operator()` function, by adjusting the subscripts. Not by modifying pointers.

Comment: @molbdnilo "It's kind of depressing that this code is from the Mathematical and Computational Sciences Division at NIST. They really should know better. " It should be noted in their defense that this file  was from a beta version, and there are more modern iterations of TNT. This was the version being used in the project I'm tasked with maintaining (and after having compiled today on GCC, this is the first I've seen of this warning/error). So in all likelihood, this library will need an upgrade and the blame shouldn't really be laid at the feet of ol' NIST.

Comment: @btmatt It hasn't changed between 1.26 (2005) and the 3.0.12 beta (2010). This was invalid long before 2005. (It probably hasn't changed since the beginning of time (1999).) It would be understandable if it were a student project, but this is NIST.

Comment: @molbdnilo, indeed, I see that this actually hasn't been corrected in the most recent version(s), and thus your criticism is definitely valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowm1_--` already has undefined behavior. It is not allowed to increment or decrement a pointer outside the bounds of the array in which it points (with the exeption of incrementing it one-past-the-object).

For this reason the condition

```
rowm1_ ++;
if(rowm1_ != NULL )
```

doesn't make sense. It is never possible to obtain a null pointer from incrementing a pointer.

I guess this is causing the analysis of the compiler to determine that you must be calling `delete[] rowm1_` on a pointer that isn't the result of `new[]`, because the only way this can work is if `rowm1_` already pointed into the array before you incremented it. Therefore the incremented pointer cannot be at offset relative to the pointer returned by `new[]`, which is however required (otherwise again undefined behavior).

Also, the null pointer check itself is pointless. It is perfectly valid to call `delete[]` on a null pointer.

You used `-Werror` to make a fatal error out of this warning, which is why it then fails to compile.

Even if you remove `-Werror` to make it compile, the resulting program will have undefined behavior and it isn't unlikely that the compiler will make similar reasoning as for the warning in order to optimize the code, potentially with very unintended outcomes.

It would be mostly luck that the compiler hasn't done any harmful optimization, if this library worked up to now. On some architectures even naively compiling the code might result in unintended behavior due to pointer overflow.

Compilers are getting better at detecting and reasoning about UB like this in order to warn the user, but at the same time they also get better at exploiting the same analysis to optimize code under the assumption that such UB does not occur. I can't say for sure that any current compiler performs an optimization that would cause problems here, but I also don't think compiler vendors guarantee that this has defined behavior. Therefore it will be more or less up to chance whether/when it will break, in potentially subtle ways.

Since the code mentions C compatibility: The same restrictions on pointer arithmetic apply in C as well. The whole concept of transparent 1-indexing can't work like this without allocating one (unused) element extra.